# I cant find my bin folder in Minecraft 1.7.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was trying to install a mod in Minecraft when I noticed that don't have a bin folder. This is in version 1.7.4.

Comment: There is no bin folder anymore. You're looking for the 1.7.4 folder, and the 1.7.4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

In the new launcher things are stored differently so to find the new jar go to versions 1.7.4 and then go on 1.7.4 not the json .The bin now only stores backups. ( Some people may not have a bin that's not a problem). Good-luck !